# connecting SLOT error

Tags: c++, qt

I have file programm.cpp that control all of my connecting page but when I want to connect one of programm.cpp functions to other push button from another class I gave an error

this is the code :

```
QObject::connect(LoginPage->Buttons->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok),SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(check_user()));
```

and this is the error :

**/home/alireza/Documents/qt/ALIREZA/programm.cpp:19: error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QPushButton*, const char*, programm* const, const char*)'**

& also this is the function declaration that completely commented :

```
void programm::check_user()
{
/*QString user = LoginPage->EditPassWord->displayText();
QString password = LoginPage->ComboUsername->currentText();

QSqlQuery myquery("SELECT Username FROM TeacherUsers");
while(myquery.next())
{
    QString Username = MyDB->query->value(0).toString();
    QString pass = MyDB->query->value(1).toString();
    qDebug()<<Username << "   " << pass ;
    //if (Username == user)
}*/
}
```

programm.h :

```
#ifndef PROGRAMM_H
#define PROGRAMM_H
#include "login.h"
#include "mainwindow.h" 
#include "nazem.h"
#include "database.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore> 
#include <QObject>

class programm
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    programm();
    Login *LoginPage;
    MainWindow *MainWindowPage;
    nazem *nazm;
    database *MyDB;
public slots :
    void check_user();
};

#endif // PROGRAMM_H
```

Comment: Is `programm::check_user()` a slot?  Is `programm` derived from `QObject`?  Have you included the `Q_OBJECT` macro in `programm`'s class declaration?

Comment: @cmannett85  : yes it is a slot(public slots) and I'm include QObject too.

Comment: The error message is telling us otherwise, please post your `programm` header.

Comment: @cmannett85 here is the programm.h !!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in comments...  You haven't derived from `QObject` and you haven't included the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Read the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots).

Comment: but qt creator don't identify Q_OBJCET and I do that by deriving from QObject and now I give `QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::check_user()`

Comment: @alirezasanaee Update your question with your new header.

Comment: I find out what you say and read doc a lit but now I give some more errors: **/home/alireza/Documents/qt/ALIREZA/programm.h:13: error: undefined reference to `vtable for programm'**

Comment: Don't forget to "run qmake" after you modify a class to derive from QObject and add that macro (so that moc can generate the code needed to provide signal-slot mechanism)

Comment: @Zlatomir I didn't get you !!, how can I add that macro in my .pro file ??

Comment: You don't add anything in the .pro file, that macro is supposed to be added in the private part of your QObject derived class.

Comment: @alirezasanaee Please read the link in the answer!  You don't add the macro to the `.pro`, you add it to each class that derives from `QObject` - which you already have done judging by your question update (although you haven't derived from `QObject`, is that just an editing mistake?).  Whenever you do this, you need to perform a rebuild - this triggers the `moc` to build the meta data to enable signals and slots.

Comment: @Zlatomir I think , I added it in QOBject derived class ,you can see it in my .h file .

Comment: @cmannett85 just a little completion a simple rebuild will not do the trick, he will also need "run qmake" and only after that he can "build"...  

alireza sanaee, as cmannett85 said you also need to derive from QObject (or another QObject derived class)

Comment: @Zlatomir You are right, but I just meant right-clicking on the project in Qt Creator and hitting 'Rebuild', which does what you say.